# Remove log files automatically after 30 days of creation

Tags: cron

I am new to linux and wondering if someone can help me. I have a RADIUS server that has multiple directories in /var/log/freeradius/radacct folder. in each directory after radacct there are log files that start with date detail- and then the date they were created(so for example detail-20210515)

I am trying to remove these files after 30 days of creation. I know cronjob can do this but  I am new to linux and just need a bit of help.

Comment: that should be most probably a kind of rotation logs, and you need take a look for rotation logs configuration files for that to mange it and delete those files after certain days of age.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `ls -l` on one of the log directories? If the product already maintains a separate log file for each day, the `find -mtime` command could help identify and remove older logs.

Comment: Take a look at `logrotate`

Answer (score 0):

I've added a find delete to the postrotate of the logrotate of /var/log/radius/radius.log

The reason for this is, the per day date stamped account files will not be processed by logrotate beyond compressing as you will never get a new file with the same date to rotate, so will not get cleaned up. The [example config](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/freeradius/raw/f33/f/freeradius-logrotate) I've looked at calls this the second technique and states:

> If you go with the second technique, you will need another cron job that removes old detail files.

For your case I would go with something like:

`find /var/log/freeradius/radacct -maxdepth 2 -mtime +30 -name "detail-*" -delete &>/dev/null`